# Change route option in Google Directions API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using Google Directions API for an Android app to show a route. I know that I can get alternatives routes if I add `&alternatives=true` to my query URL.

But is it possible to query a route with these options from Google Maps:

[image]

Can I add something like `&routes=best` to my URL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Restrictions), you can only impose *restrictions*, which include these three parameters:

- avoid=tolls
- avoid=highways
- avoid=ferries

and their combinations as well. To add this to your request write `avoid=tolls` for a single param request or `avoid=elem1|elem2|elem3` for a combination of parameters.

You can however use these parameters for what you need:

> *transit_routing_preference* — Specifies preferences for transit routes. Using this parameter, you can bias the options returned, rather than accepting the default best route chosen by the API. This parameter may only be specified for transit directions, and only if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps API for Work client ID. The parameter supports the following arguments:
>
> *less_walking* indicates that the calculated route should prefer limited amounts of walking
>
> *fewer_transfers* indicates that the calculated route should prefer a limited number of transfers.